# Model complex permissions based on groups

Tags: plone, zope

I am trying to model the following permissions in Plone and would like to know the best approach I should take:

Group 1 - Senior members
  Group 2 - members

Group 3 - Senior members
  Group 2 - members

1. All the members in the groups shouldn't be able to view any content item associated with them.
2. Senior members should be able to view and amend content items within their sub groups but should not be able to view each others content items - these content items all have a user_id field to indicate who the content belongs.
3. Members in sub groups should not be able to view content associated with senior members nor each others content items.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going to get the same answers here as you got with your mailing list post: http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/Implementing-bespoke-access-control-levels-in-Plone-td6986879.html

You'll need to write your own local role adapter using http://pypi.python.org/pypi/borg.localrole. Perhaps take a look at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/borg.project as well and the article introducing it: http://www.martinaspeli.net/articles/developing-with-plone-3-borg.localrole-and

Comment: Thanks Laurence, really appreciate that and sorry for being such a dunce, I had totally forgotten about the mailing list post on Plone!

Answer (score 0):

Try using collective.subscribable sections.  I haven't fully tested it yet, but it seems to be doing the job for me.  I went the borg.localrole route, and it was a major pain, and I was never happy with my solution.

Comment: Assigning local roles seems a good match for the subscribable sections case, I just don't think you can model the "Edit anything but my own record" case without calculating roles programmatically. There is no way to *subtract* permissions from a user with a particular role in Zope/Plone.

Comment: That would be a good point, except that I don't see where he's asked to "Edit anything but my own record"...